# Drawing pixels on top of Gstreamer

Tags: python, video, drawing, pygtk, python-gstreamer

I'm trying to build an application in Python that can draw things on top of video. I have not found a way to do this using gstreamer + Tkinter; I don't think tk lets you do transparent Canvases. So I've looked at using gtk instead, but I'm a bit lost- I would *like* to be able to just drop some sort of transparent overlay on top and push pixels, but I don't think there's such a thing as a transparent DrawingArea, either. So I need a way to edit the contents of a DrawingArea after each frame of video is in it but before it's shown to the screen. I tried using expose-event but that hasn't worked.

Any suggestions on where to go from here? I want my final product to be a little interface to let the user draw lines and polygons on top of a video as well as drawing pixels programatically- and, if possible, save the result to frames and/or video. So a direction that is more likely to make that possible would be preferred.

Edit: Tried using the "handoff" signal but it flickers madly. PiTiVi has a custom Pipeline that has a state-changed signal which they use to draw lines and circles with Cairo. So this is totally doable...

Edit 2: Right, okay. PiTiVi only draws when the video is paused; I guess I can deal with that. That's what it was using the state changed signal for- you can watch for state change messages and emulate a signal. I can deal with that, but it would be really nice to draw over every frame.